# Corrupted Data Format in CSV file - Single row data split among 2 rows. Quick fix needed

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, corruption

I have 100's of csv files which appears to be corrupt. All files have the same common problem. Each file has 5 headers but the data is always split among 2 rows e.g.

[image]

I was thinking of a python script to correct this and was wondering if there is a function or library that can do this quickly rather than writing a whole script to adjust it. The expected format is below. How can I correct this for all files.

[image: v]

Comment: Do you understand what `setText` actually does?  Have you specified the type of data the `JEditorPane` is been expected to renderer?  You might like to take a look at [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: I have previously looked at the website. I am not sure what you mean by what data type JEditorPane is expected to render. I am getting text from xml and returning strings to the JEditorPane.

Comment: You need to set the expected [`contentType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)) before it will know how to render the content.  Personally, a `JTextPane` or `JTextArea` would be simpler...

Comment: http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html could be useful